# strftime - how to get 1 letter abbreviation

Tags: r, strftime

`%B` gives me: June

`%b`gives me: Jun

How can I get just the first letter? e.g. J for June. M for March. F for February?

Comment: You can use `substr` i.e. `substr(strftime(x, "%b"), 1, 1)` but wouldn't it create confusion for `June/July` or `April/August`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it can create a confusion if you only have one month, but usually, months are displayed in sequence so the context makes it clear. When you see M A M J J A, it is evident which one is May, which one is April etc.

Answer (score 2):

If the months are in sequence and there is no confusion, then we can use `substr`

```
substr(strftime(x, "%b"), 1, 1)
```

where 'x' is the datetime `vector`